# Can I pass in a username and password into Google Api signIn

Tags: google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I have an application that uses APIs that need to be authorization, and I want to pass in an email address and password to a dummy account instead of having the the user authorize the application with their own log in data.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do. Also, it would be nice if you show the community what you have tried.

Comment: You can generally only use OAuth for Google APIs. Occasional portions of the APIs allow some access if authenticated with an API key. Consider configuring a Service Account as a "playground" for users.